# r - Setting custom projection in PROJ >=5 paradigm

Tags: coordinate-system, r, proj, rgdal

Before PROJ >=5.0, one could set a custom projection centered anywhere in the world by adjusting the `+lon_0=`and `+lat_0=` arguments in proj4string specification.

For example, a projection centered on Europe.

```
proj <- CRS("+proj=laea +lat_0=53 +lon_0=9 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
```

As I understand it, the use of proj4string is being phased out, and this sort of use is discouraged.

So, with the new projection specification methods in R (e.g. WKT2) is there way to set a custom-centered projection? And if not, is anyone aware of a different automated way of selecting a roughly appropriate projection based on a set of X,Y coordinates (e.g. the centroid)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could template the WKT2 version i.e.

```
lon_0 <- 9
lat_0 <- 53
x_0 <- 4321000
y_0 <- 3210000
template <- "+proj=laea +lat_0={lat_0} +lon_0={lon_0} +x_0={x_0} +y_0={y_0} +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

EDIT: I didn't mention dropping `towgs84` and `ellps` here, my take is if WGS84 is the datum and is recognized for later transformation then use that, if towgs84 is all zeroes just drop it.  The 2020-campaign against projstrings is ostensibly explained in these posts:

https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/PROJ6_GDAL3.html

Now convert that to wkt2 with `sf::st_crs(glue::glue(template))$wkt` (only since sf Nov 2019 or so), and swap out the parameters with similar text replacement. That way if you need a specific local datum or other authority tweaks you can modify the appropriate wkt2 version.

(`sprintf` does the same as glue, but the glue way is a bit more convenient)

fwiw, my current understanding is that `ellps=WGS84` and `towgs84` (with zero params) is unnecessary, 'datum=WGS84' is perfectly well understood by PROJ/GDAL.

Possibly a better starting point, is something like this (I don't know how much the PROJCS name matters if at all). I will need this kind of thing for myself I'm only starting to explore it.  I copied this from `testepsg (GDAL)` output of `ESRI:102020`.

```r
   lon_0 <- 9
    lat_0 <- 53
    x_0 <- 4321000
    y_0 <- 3210000

tmp <- 'PROJCS["Ad_hoc_handy_wkt2_template_for_laea",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",{lat_0}],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",{lon_0}],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",{x_0}],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",{y_0}],
    UNIT["metre",1]]'

sf::st_crs(glue::glue(tmp))
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   User input: PROJCS["Ad_hoc_handy_wkt2_template_for_laea",
#> GEOGCS["WGS 84",
#>     DATUM["WGS_1984",
#>         SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],
#>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
#>     UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#> PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
#> PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",53],
#> PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",9],
#> PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],
#> PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],
#> UNIT["metre",1]] 
#>   wkt:
#> PROJCRS["Ad_hoc_handy_wkt2_template_for_laea",
#>     BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
#>         DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
#>             ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
#>                 LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
#>                     ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
#>         PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#>             ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
#>     CONVERSION["unnamed",
#>         METHOD["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
#>             ID["EPSG",9820]],
#>         PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",53,
#>             ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
#>             ID["EPSG",8801]],
#>         PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",9,
#>             ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
#>             ID["EPSG",8802]],
#>         PARAMETER["False easting",4321000,
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
#>             ID["EPSG",8806]],
#>         PARAMETER["False northing",3210000,
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
#>             ID["EPSG",8807]]],
#>     CS[Cartesian,2],
#>         AXIS["(E)",east,
#>             ORDER[1],
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
#>         AXIS["(N)",north,
#>             ORDER[2],
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Caveat, obviously you should check in your context for the appropriateness of a given chunk of metadata like this.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. 

My aim is to have an automatically-generated LAEA projection that centers on the input data. How else might one need to adjust the metadata for this? Seems like this should be stable if the same DATUM and PROJECTION are always used.

Comment: Definitely ,you only need a different datum if you have specific local requirements.

Comment: Nice! Is the second approach "possibly a better starting point" mainly because it allows one to supply a `PROJCS` name, or do you know of other advantages?

Comment: I guess because WKT2 seems like it will have longevity, it's now *the right format* to use. The thing I find weird about all this is having no good shortcut to create a projection, but shortcuts are the cause of all the ambiguity, so listing all parameters explicitly is " the solution", though there's nothing to stop me using bad names for things. We'll just end up with more ad hoc shortcuts of all kinds, I don't see why the war on projstrings has to be so aggressive - if WGS84 datum is sufficient for your work, then just let it be.

Comment: Preach! @mdsumner I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @mdsumner Thanks. It's helpful to know that I'm not the only one who finds this somewhat baffling. For example, the r-spatial blog post you linked to mentions that "use of so-called PROJ4-strings (like `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84`) are discouraged". But then the first example in the [PROJ (7.0.1) project's Quick start guide](https://proj.org/usage/quickstart.html) is the proj string `+proj=merc +lat_ts=56.5 +ellps=GRS80` followed by many many other examples throughout the documentation. But I'll just take your advice, and keep using EPSG and allowable proj strings whenever they're allowed.